# Why does R's strftime return the previous month for midnight?

Tags: r, datetime, strftime

This is right on the borderline and is a pathological case, but it is causing me trouble:

```
> strftime(as.POSIXct('2016-07-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%m')
[1] "06"
```

Seems like it should be 7, even though I know it's midnight. These are 7:

```
> strftime(as.POSIXct('2016-07-02', tz = 'UTC'), '%m')
[1] "07"
> strftime(as.POSIXct('2016-07-01'), '%m')
[1] "07"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strftime` function is defaulting to your time zone, thus midnight UTC is still the previous day for all points west.

Either add the "tz=" option to `strftime` function:

```
 strftime(as.POSIXct('2016-07-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%m', tz="UTC")
[1] "07"
```

or use the `format` function:

```
format(as.POSIXct('2016-07-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%m')
[1] "07"
```

Comment: Thanks Dave2e and @dario. Tough call for selected answer, but awarded to Dave2e for explaining how the system not being UTC affects the result.

Answer (score 3):

Adding timezone to `strftime`   :

```
strftime(as.POSIXct('2016-07-01', tz = 'UTC'), '%m', tz="UTC")
[1] "07"
```

Explanation:

You only specified a timezone for `as.POSIXct`. Then you use `strftime` **without** specifying the timezone, which causes `strftime` to fall back on its defaults

From `?strftime`:

> **tz** A character string specifying the time zone to be used for the conversion. System-specific (see as.POSIXlt)

If your system time-zone is not `UTC` it could cause this discrepancy.